# How to use Google Maps JavaScript API v3's Geocoding Service in Filter.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am using [filter.js](https://github.com/jiren/filter.js) in a website along with Google Maps API V3 as it shows in [its demo/example(of filter.js)](http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/filterjs-map.html) with only one difference, my requirements are to use Address instead of Latitude or Longitude and as far I know it could be done using Geocoding Service of Google Maps. I have to modify some of my code:

**Before**

```
addMarker: function(salon){
    var that = this;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(salon.lat, salon.lng),
      map: this.map,
      title: salon.title
    });

    marker.info_window_content = salon.title + '<br/> Treatments: ' + salon.treatments + '<br/> Booking: ' + salon.bookings_1 + '<br/> Address: ' + salon.address + '<br/><a href="' + salon.permalink + '"> View Full Details </a>'
    this.markers[salon.id] = marker

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      that.infowindow.setContent(marker.info_window_content)
      that.infowindow.open(that.map,marker);
    });
  },
```

**After**

```
addMarker: function(salon){
    //new line for address 
    var salonaddress = salon.address1 + ' ' + salon.address2 + ' ' + salon.address3 + ', ' + salon.city + ', ' + salon.state + ' ' + salon.postal_code + ', ' + salon.country ;
    console.log(" salonaddress: " + salonaddress)
    var that = this;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': salonaddress}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          that.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: this.map,
              title: salon.title,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
          marker.info_window_content = salon.title + '<br/> Treatments: ' + salon.treatments + '<br/> Booking: ' + salon.bookings_1 + '<br/> Address: ' + salon.address + '<br/><a href="' + salon.   permalink + '"> View Full Details </a>'
            that.markers[salon.id] = marker

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              that.infowindow.setContent(marker.info_window_content)
              that.infowindow.open(that.map,marker);
            });

        } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });

  },
```

It looks like its working but it is not showing markers on map at all. Trying to find my mistake but after many hours still could not fix it. Can any one point out my coding mistake?

Comment: How many salons are you attempting to show on the map? Are you getting any javascript errors?  What is the value of `this.map`? What console output are you getting? Can you provide a jsfiddle that shows the problem (or a link to a live map that does)?

Comment: Number of salons are dynamic. No javascript errors. Please go to this URL ( http://b-card.co.uk/search/ ) for live example. You just need to type "London" in search field and bit search button.

Comment: I see 2 markers on that page (if I zoom out).  I see 4 entries on the side bar, but 3 of them are at the same place (238 High Street South Eastham , London, , E6 3PG).

Comment: Yes, because I changed "this" to "that" in my code, that is why you are seeing it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed "this" to "that" in following code and it some how fixed my issue. Not sure about the logic yet.

Before:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: this.map,
              title: salon.title,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
```

After:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              map: that.map,
              title: salon.title,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
          });
```